# The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your Macro security settings

Tags: powerpoint, add-in

I am getting the error that appears in the title and I already check the security settings, I have everything enabled and the Add-in is signed. I put the screenshot of how I have the options. If I have everything enable why it can give security problems?

[image]

[image]

I am using windows 8 and office 365. And the add-in that is not working is a powerpoint add-in. I try also some solutions that appears in this thread but no one works for me: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b385af0-9856-4cfb-bc48-3369c3ce2ace/when-opening-ms-word-the-macro-cannot-be-found-or-has-been-disabled-because-of-your-macro-security?forum=officeitproprevious

Comment: You can get this message if your ribbon or button code calls a macro that's not present (ie, the name's misspelled or the macro is declared as a private sub)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that in some computers it works and in other it doesn't. And I put the same security settings in all of them.

Comment: VBA became an install option at some point in the past.  It's still installed by default but might have been disabled by the user/admin.  Have the user press Alt+F11 ... see if the VBA IDE launches.

Comment: yes the VBA IDE launches when Alt + F11 is pressed... There doesn't appear the addIn but it is loading somehow because the addIn creates a new tab in the powerpoint options and it is appearing. But when you try to click on the tab it gives the error that I put in the thread.

Comment: How have you installed the add-in (via the Add-ins dialog box or otherwise) and is it a PPA/PPAM add-in or a COM addin?

Comment: It is a ppam add-in and I add it using advance installer. With this program I installed a msi file that contains the ppam, the registry values and other files that I need. It is working in all the computers that I test except 2 that are giving this error (some of them with the same OS and office version and works well).

Comment: Have you actually checked the registry to see that the needed values are there?  I occasionally run into situations where my installers aren't allowed to make the reg settings I need.

Comment: I tried deleting it and use the ppam file to insert it manually in powerpoint Add-Ins (with that the registry values are suppose to be well set) and I get the same error.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest, but try the suggestion here:  http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/TW_users/conversations/topics/62896

Comment: This one also didn't work... I am contacting with microsoft support center because even a simple "Hello world" macro is not working. If you exec it from the code it works but as soon as you create a ppam file and add it, it gives error. I will post the solution here if they provide it to me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, and yes, PLEASE do post any answer you receive.  Very interested to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the EXACT same problem with an addin which I developed for Powerpoint many years ago and now ran on some computers at my new company, but not others.

The support couldn't help me and Google couldn't really help me, but this thread came closest to describing my situation.

The only common denominator I eventually found was that 32-bit Office could run the addin, but not 64-bit.

So my solution was to go through the VBA source code and replace my declaration variables according to this Microsoft post:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg264421.aspx

Maybe that could help you as well?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I had the same problem,. and could not find any solutions untill this!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple PowerPoint presentation and save it as pp_HelloWorld.pptx

Add the following VBA procedure

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbHelloWorld()
 MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

to a module in this presentation and save it as pp_HelloWorld.pptm

Close and reopen this presentation pp_HelloWorld.pptm and the macro will work from the Developer > Macros > Run option

Put the following custom ribbon code

```
<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:qat/>
        <mso:tabs>
        <mso:tab id="mso_c1.2A492F1" label="New Tab">
            <mso:group id="mso_c2.2A492F1" label="New Group" autoScale="true">
                <mso:button id="sbHelloWorld" label="sbHelloWorld" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="sbHelloWorld" visible="true"/>
            </mso:group>
        </mso:tab>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

into a file called PowerPoint.officeUI

and put this file in the folder

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office

(this may be hidden initially)

Close and reopen this presentation pp_HelloWorld.pptm and the macro will work from the Developer > Macros > Run option

The macro will not work from the macro button New Tab > sbHelloWorld and gives the message -

**"The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your Macro security settings"**

Next Clear the Trusted Documents -

[image]

Developer > Macro Settings > Trusted Documents > Clear

The macro now works from the macro button New Tab > sbHelloWorld.

This works on Windows 10 with Office 365

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happens when normal.dotm has become corrupt. So the best and quickest solution is to **restore the normal.dotm** from a recent backup.

Comment: Right answer, wrong program. This is a thread about PowerPoint, which doesn't look at normal.dotm

Answer (score 0):

I too had an old PowerPoint addin that stopped working.  As soon as I switched to the 32-bit Office, it worked again.  Two of my customers using the same addin successfully re-enabled it by switching to 32-bit Office.